# Redirect to its own page

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile-website

I'm new in asp.net C#.

I am creating a website especially for mobile users.

I want to redirect the page to the user mobile version and its platform.

I don't want to use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/wurfl.php)

and also this http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Are there any other possible way to create the pages for different mobile users?

For example different pages for android (ice cream) and android (gingerbread) etc...

Comment: You may want to evaluate the `useragent` string and use this to control the redirect.

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET Web Forms, ASP.NET Web Pages or ASP.NET MVC (if MVC which version? 1,2,3 or 4)?

Answer (score 2):

Use this `Request.UserAgent` like this:

```
if(Request.UserAgent.Contains("Android"))
{
    Response.Redirect("Andriod/MyPage.aspx");
}
```

Version checking too can be done the same way. User agents for all popular Os / browsers are readily available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScripts Navigator. Something like this:

```
p = navigator.platform;

// Detects if it is an iOS device
if( p === 'iPad' || p === 'iPhone' || p === 'iPod' ){
    //iOS = true;
    //Redirect
}

// Detects if it is an Android device
if(p.indexOf("android")>=0);
    //Android= true;
    //Redirect
}
```

or

```
var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i) ? true : false );
if(iOS)
    //Redicret
```